# Why is namedtuple rename=True renaming an "_z" field

Tags: python, namedtuple

So "_z" is not a keyword, and is a value identifier.

```
print("_z".isidentifier())
```

returns True

```
import keyword
print(keyword.iskeyword("_z"))
```

returns False

So why is named tuple renaming the column?

```
Point3D = namedtuple('Point3D', ['x','y','_z'], rename=True)


c = Point3D(10,20,30)
c._fields
```

returns ('x', 'y', '_2')

Comment: `Any valid Python identifier may be used for a fieldname except for names starting with an underscore` https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Because reasons - this is layed down in the documentation for named tuples. Why call it `_z` anyhow?

Comment: so any valid field name except for something starting with an underscore, so the name it picks for me is "_0" as an alternative???

Comment: All the information is in the docs... `invalid fieldnames are automatically replaced with positional names. For example, ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'abc'] is converted to ['abc', '_1', 'ghi', '_3']`